# How can I get faster the .index() of an element that have some class?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Suppose I have these elements :

```
​<div class="myClass" id="class_3">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="myClass" id="class_1">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="NOTTHIS">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="myClass" id="class_0">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="myClass" id="class_2">&nbsp;</div>
```

how can I get faster with jQuery the index of the element `class_0` valutating only the elements with class `myClass`

In the example should be 2, not 3!

Comment: you want if the class_0 then myclass property effect the page  rite ?

Comment: You are asking for a "faster" way, which implies that you currently have a working solution.  We will need to see your current code to determine if our solution is faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method, as simple as that:

```
$("#class_0").index(".myClass");
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be the other way around?

Comment: @JasperdeVries Nope: http://jsfiddle.net/pE4hk/. Basing on the method description: *Search for a given element from among the matched elements*.

Comment: @JasperdeVries it can actually sort of be done in reverse as well, but this works.  http://jsfiddle.net/uSsQz/

Comment: @JamesMontagne Yes, but we are talking about the *faster* solution. At least one `$()` less :)

Comment: Sorry, was looking at the `element` version: `$(".myClass").index($("#class_0"));`

Comment: ... what a confusing documentation

Comment: @vision Right, I fully agree that is better.  I was just giving an example to illustrate the difference in the two method signatures of `index`.  As @jasper pointed out, it's a bit of a confusing method.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Agreed, I also often mix the sequence of the selectors.